# Using 年代 for decades when using 昭和XX年 for individual years

Tags: time

If you are describing a year as

> 昭和４１年

rather than

> １９６６年

Can you similarly use 年代 for decades, such as

> 昭和４０年代

or does that convention only apply when using the Christian calendar

Comment: Short answer is: yes you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use 年代 like that. 昭和40年代 refers to 1965–1974.

Note that 年代 does not always refer to *decades*. For example, 1600年代 typically refers to 1600–1699.

Comment: I temporarily confused 時代 with 年代. I edited it now. I had meant to ask about 年代.

Comment: Why would X年代 refer to a period starting with X for decades but ending stricly before X for centuries?  Does 1600年代 really mean 1 year before 16世紀？

Comment: @Kimball Oh, sorry, it was a simple mistake. 1600年代 refers to 1600-1699, 16世紀 refers to 1501-1600.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense.